Sufficient condition for moving limit?
If we are told that the integral
$$\int f(x,y)dx$$
converges, then can we say that
$$\lim_{y\to0}\int f(x,y)dx = \int \lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)dx$$?
If this isn't enough information, what do we need to know in addition about $f$ in order to be able to move the limit inside the integral?

Check out Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem.

I read up on it but unfortunately it is stated in terms too complicated for me to understand.

Edit your post to include more details about your specific situation.

@TedShifrin it is all included in the OP, it is really just the question: "if the integral converges, can I take the limit inside the integral/and vice-versa?" Apparently, the answer is "NO"

since you said that the Dominated Convergence theorem is too complicated, I think Ted suggested to add you maths background

The standard counterexample is (something like) $f(x, y) = 1/y$ for $x \in (0, y)$ and $f(x, y) = 0$ else.
